# tkinter's IntVar() and .get()'ing it

Tags: python, tkinter

Im in a need of a little help here, i feel like i have searched endlessly and been unable to corret my problem.

The case:

I have a checkbutton which have on value as 1 and off as 0, now i want to do an act if it is on and another if it is off.

My code goes:

```
#==Checkbox==#

check = IntVar()
checkbox = Checkbutton(labelframe, text="Tillad mere end én linje", variable = check, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
checkbox.pack(side = RIGHT)

...

def go():

        check.get()

        print(check)

        if(check == 0):

                print("off")

                w.delete(ALL)
                tegnefladen()
                update()

        else:

                print("on")
                update()
```

Comment: Everytime i run this it will automaticly run the else, regardless of the buttonstatus. Have tried to print the "check" but outcome is PY_VAR0.

Comment: Every bit of information helps, and that bit was exactly what was needed. Next time, please include more details;-)

Comment: No problem, just trying to help you to get answers easier, and become a valued member of the community;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't actually setting the value. `check` is an object, and it won't ever be identical to 0. Basically, you want to compare `check.get()`. Try this:

```
def go():
        print(check.get())
        if(check.get() == 0):

                print("off")

                w.delete(ALL)
                tegnefladen()
                update()

        else:

                print("on")
                update()
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed good sir!

This resolved my problem :-)

Comment: Awesome;-) If you could accept/upvote it, I would much appreciate!